# Why is python importing `scipy` even though I haven't asked it to?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have a file `constants.py` from which I want to import a constant `SEED`.

When I run

```py
from constants import SEED
```

I get

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'SEED' from 'scipy.optimize._highs.constants' 
(/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_highs/constants
.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I would understand this if my file was called `scipy/optimize/_highs/constants.py` but `constants.py` is in my local dir.

Also, why is python looking several layers deep in scipy? How is it getting `from constants import SEED` and `from scipuy.optimize._highs.constants import SEED` mixed up?

I am running code on the RAPIDS Paperspace gradient image.

My `sys.path`

```py
['/notebooks/TPS-12/analysis', # The dir my notebook + constants.py is in
 '/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/root/.ipython']
```

Comment: Most likely anaconda is doing some non-standard job behind this.

Comment: What is your SciPy version? I can reproduce this with SciPy 1.6.0, but not with SciPy 1.7.0 (Python version used is 3.9.7, no Conda).

Answer (score 1):

If you've recently updated your IDE, have you tried to update scipy? I know that's what I had to do when I was using Anaconda. Even if you're using a different IDE it's worth a shot.

Additionally, there might be relevant information [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13350). To summarize, try renaming your "constants" module to something else.

Comment: Ouch, that sounds like a bad bug in SciPy.

Comment: But seems to have been fixed with release 1.7.0.

Comment: That might be the fix then, is to update to 1.7.0.

Comment: Updating scipy version fixed the problem